# Problems Solving Recurrence T(n) = 4T(n/4) + 3log n

Tags: performance, algorithm, recursion, asymptotic-complexity

I'm really getting frustrated about solving the Recurrence above. I was trying to solve it by using the Master Method, but I just didn't get it done...

I'm having a recursive algorithm that takes 3log n times (three binary searches) to identify four sub-problems, each with with a size of n/4, and then solves them individually until n is smaller than some constant given by input. So I got this recurrence as a result:

```
T(n) = 4*T(n/4) + 3*log(n)

Base-Case if n < c (c = some constant given by program input):

T(n) = 1
```

I'm trying to find the asymptotic running time of my recursive program, and wanted to solve it by using the master theorem. Can anybody tell me if it's possible to use the master theorem with this recurrence, and if yes, which case of the master theorem is it?

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: your question is very elusive; I have a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve, what has not worked or what you tried for that matter. Please be a bit more explicit. Some code samples would help to!

Comment: @Pandrei I want to analyse the running time of my recursive algorithm and wanted to know if you can solve this recursive recurrence by using the master theorem, and if I can use it, how I can solve the recurrence.

Comment: @ChristophGerl the master theorem allows you to calculate the running time of a recursive algorithm by using the big O notation. What do you mean solve the recurrence?

Comment: @Pandrei Oh well, sorry I made a mistake there... Sure, I want to find my Algorithm's running time in terms of the Big O notation. I thought you also call it "to solve the recurrence" because T(n) is the recurrence.

Comment: When you start getting into questions that involve more 'sciency' than 'programmery' aspects (the master theorem and asymptotic complexity) you may find that [cs.stackexchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) would be able to give a more in depth answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T(n) = O(n)`, because a logarithm of 4 base 4 is 1 and 3 * log(n) is `O(n ^ 0.5)`(0.5 < 1). It corresponds to the first case of the Master theorem as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought the constant of n^c need to be an Integer.